# SQL Update in Yii

Tags: sql, yii

Given the following UPDATE query in my controller

```
$connection = yii::app()->db;
$sql = "UPDATE list SET Status = 'R' WHERE ".$_POST['ListId']."=".$_POST['RListId'];
$command=$connection->createCommand($sql);
$command->execute();
```

This is changing every record to `Status = 'R'` not just the one with the matching parameters. `$_POST['ListId']` and `$_POST['RListId']` are exactly what I need and I have verified them though var_dump in the controller.

What is wrong with my query?

Comment: What are those two variables?  (Besides being what you need)?

Comment: Hogan they are integer's (see comment on Adrian Cornish answer).  Regardless I am trying to only update records where A=B regardless of what they are.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have no field name in your where clause. So it could be where you have 1=1 which evaluates to true for every record.

As a guess I think you want something like this

```
Yii::app()->db
    ->createCommand("UPDATE list SET Status = 'R' WHERE ListId=:ListId OR RListID=:RListID")
    ->bindValues(array(':ListId' => $_POST['ListId'], ':RListID' => $_POST['RListId']))
    ->execute();
```

Comment: Adrian Cornish thanks for the response.  Yes these values are integers [id's of the records].  So if I am updating a record in a given table where ListId = 1 I only want that associated record (RListId) to be updated in the other table `list`

Comment: I went back and reread your answer and yes that pointed out my problem...added a field name in clause and works as it should.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Please do not code like this, this query is wide open to SQL injection.